# How to use a variable to be searched in the next method?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to do searches in a list of dictionaries (I got that, great) that comes from a .json, but I needed the term to be searched for in the function `next(item for item in aux if item["name"] == 'brad'))` were the one read through the input, but my attempts to pass the variable and not the value directly, they just return an error that the variable doesn't exist.

Code:

```
import json

with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as meu_json:
    aux = json.loads(meu_json.read())

# var = input('write the name: ')
# print('value in var: ' + var)
print(next(item for item in aux if item["name"] == "name to search or 'var' " ))
```

If I pass it directly (a name that I know exists in .json):

```
 print(next(item for item in aux if item["name"] == "Charles Cote" ))
```

I get the desired output:

```
 {'name': 'Charles Cote', 'parcel_id': '1303852', 'civic': 1216, 'street': 'Boulevard René-Lévesque Ouest', 'city': 'Québec'}
```

But I need to pass the name of the variable that holds what comes from the form  ('var'):

```
 print(next(item for item in aux if item["name"] == var ))
```

But my attempts only return to me:

```
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

Eu consegui fazer a pesquisa que eu precisava usando um for:

```
 for sub in aux:
        if sub["name"] == var:
            saida = sub
    print(saida)
```

Input:

```
write the name: Marie Fournier
```

Print confirming what you entered:

```
value in var: Marie Fournier
```

Output (Which is exactly what I needed):

```
{'name': 'Marie Fournier', 'parcel_id': '1532723', 'civic': 707, 'street': "Rue de l'Alsace", 'city': 'Québec'}
```

Comment: In future please don't post images of code as it is hard to read and debug. Putting braces around `{var}` is unnecessary and will break things (this is creating a set).

Comment: add the expected out or whatever as code not an image

Comment: You are trying to next a, for the most part, `non-existent` or value you can handle later. `next` is supposed to keep track of where it is as a variable. So, assign it to a variable and then call next (not sure why you would call next to begin with).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @match Thanks for the tip about attaching images, and {var} was just to demonstrate that the ways I tried to concatenate my var there weren't successful.

Comment: @gold_cy Thanks for the tip about attaching images. I edited and tried to explain better.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the tip about attaching images.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama To be honest I also didn't know if using next would work in this case, I just tried it because that's what I saw about searching in dictionaries list, but I solved it with a for loop without using the next function (I think I did).
Thank you for your attention.